# $\lim\sup$ of a bounded sequence and convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

For a bounded sequence $(x_n)$ of real numbers, I am trying to prove the following:

If $k=\lim\sup x_n$, then there is a subsequence of $(x_n)$ which converges to $k$.

The way I proceeded is as below.

$\lim\sup x_n=k$ means $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sup\{x_n, x_{n+1}, x_{n+2}, \ldots \}=k$.

Now the sequence $(\sup\{x_n,x_{n+1}, x_{n+2},\ldots\})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is monotonically decreasing and bounded (as $(x_n)$ is bounded), hence, it is not only convergent, but its limit is its infimum.

Thus, $k$ is nothing but the infimum of the sequence $(\sup\{x_n,x_{n+1}, x_{n+2},\ldots\})_{n=1}^{\infty}$.

So, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is $r=r_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$ such that
$$
k \le \sup\{ x_{r}, x_{r+1}, x_{r+2}, \ldots\} < k+\varepsilon.
$$
This was the hint told, but after this, I couldn't proceed to construct the subsequence explicitly. Can one tell me how to proceed after this, or is there any alternate way to construct a subsequence converging to $k$?

**Where I confused** For $\varepsilon>0$, there is $r$, which may depend on $\varepsilon$, such that above inequality hold. But I asked myself, if such $r$ is independent of $\varepsilon$, what will happen?

Like, if a given sequence $(x_n)$ is in $(0,1)$ and it has a subsequence $(1/2, 2/3, 3/4, \ldots)$, then it is clear that in above equation, the $\sup\{ x_{r}, x_{r+1}, x_{r+2}, \ldots\}$ will always be $1$, and so $\lim\sup x_n$ will be $1$. But, how to **recover** the existence of sequence  $(1/2, 2/3, 3/4, \ldots)$ or other which has limit $1$?

Comment: This looks good so far. Consider for each $m \in \mathbb N$ choosing $\epsilon = 1/m$. Then there is some $r(m)$ (i.e. an $r$ depending on $m$) such that $k \leq \sup\{x_{r(m)}, x_{r(m)+1}, x_{r(m)+2}, \ldots\} < k + 1/m$. Form a subsequence $(x_{n_m})_{m=1}^{\infty}$ by choosing $n_m \in \{r(m), r(m)+1, r(m)+2, \ldots\}$. Can you do this in such a way that $(n_m)_{m=1}^{\infty}$ is a strictly increasing sequence?

Comment: The problem I am facing is that, how do we guarantee that for different $m$, we can choose different $r(m)$? So, in the example at last para, same $r(m)$ will come since $\sup\{x_{r(m)}, x_{r(m)+1}, \ldots \}$ is always $k=1$.

Comment: "So, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is $r = r_{\epsilon}$..." - I assume you are OK with this part? In my previous comment I'm choosing $\epsilon = 1/m$ and instead of writing $r_{\epsilon}$ I'm writing $r_m$. (You could call it $r_{1/m}$ if you prefer.) The point is that there exists such an $r$, and in general it will depend on $\epsilon$ (or equivalently, on $m$).

Comment: Sorry, I will think on it. I am confused exactly there.